# Highcharts lines not displaying in mshta

Tags: iframe, highcharts, hta

I have created a chart using Highcharts and it renders fine in Firefox and IE. However, when the chart is rendered in mshta, the scale lines disappear and the labels on the x-axis and y-axis become blurry. The plot lines and the samples also look much thinner in mshta than in IE or firefox. The event which is supposed to fire upon clicking the chart doesn't work either. 
The charts are rendering inside nested iframes...

mshta
--Nested iframe
  
  --Nested iframe
    
    --Highchart

I've tried including the meta tag with the http-equiv attribute as 'X-UA-Compatible' and content as 'IE9'. However, there is no change in the rendering. Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Comment: Have you set [`application="yes"`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21707903/1169519) for the `iframe`s? Also HTML5 DTD might help in some cases.

Comment: do you have any live demo?